# errors in rails 4.0 to 4.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, bundle

Recently I'd upgrade rails 4.0 to 4.1, creating new app work's fine but while run another existent one, it throw an error.

After generate an app using "rails new appname" work fine, the error come with the olders one (4.0 old)

```
rails server

/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:34:in `block in setup': You have already activated sprockets 2.12.1, but your Gemfile requires sprockets 2.11.0. Prepending `bundle exec` to your command may solve this. (Gem::LoadError) from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:19:in `setup'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler.rb:127:in `setup'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler.rb:132:in `require'
from /home/lazaro/ejemplo/config/application.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:126:in `require'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:126:in `require'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:146:in `require_application_and_environment!'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:68:in `console'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:40:in `run_command!'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:135:in `require'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:135:in `rescue in require'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:144:in `require'
from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Show your `Gemfile`. Did you make `bundle update`?

Comment: thanks for your answer zishe, already excec it, there is my Gemfile http://hastebin.com/zibafocayo.vhdl

Comment: I think it conflicts with `sass-rails` version. Try to remove version of it, also `coffee-rails` and make `bundle update`

Comment: SOLVED!!!

`gem uni sprockets`

ALL the versions

and the bundle install